# Random 4x4 2D NSArray Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create a Minesweeper game.
I have a 4x4 set of buttons equally spaced in main.Storyboard.

My plan is to create a random array which places a 0 or * in the 1st/2nd/3rd/4th arrays.  I would do this by using the arc4Random method.

With the remaining blank cells, I then have to check how many mines there could be for the 8 (potential) squares around the cell/button.  This would be governed by the boundary conditions (0,0 to 3,3).

Once this is set up, I would then set the background and number label to the same colour.  I could then write an if or else statement to change the colour after each button is pressed.

I'm quite struggling how to start this off and actually write this.  Can anyone please give me some advice please?

Comment: Why `NSArray` when it's fixed-size?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

you can get a boolean like this.

```
bool hasMine = arc4random() % 2;
```

this will give you 50% chance to get a bomb... if you want less bomb, increase the value (3 will give you 2 bomb free square, for one with a bomb, etc..)

then a "" or a "*" like this;

```
NSSString * value = hasMine ? @"*" : @"" ;
```

then it's just a matter of a for loop to populate your arrays.

for the sake of performance, I wouldn't use a n x n nested array but a single arrray of nxn size (in your case a array with 16 value). Then I will set a tag for 0 to (nxn -1) to each button based on its position, and on click I'll get the tag of the pressed button and retrive the value of the object at this position in the array